# matlab: align 3D shapes

Tags: matlab, alignment

I am looking for a way to align 3D shapes. I have matrices AB, A, and B, each  contains a 3D item. Matrix AB is composed of A and B.

I would like to find the transformation (rotation, translation) needed for A and B to rebuild AB.

Do you have any methodology, or useful functions that could help me ?

Regards.

Comment: Some clarifications: Are A,B,AB 2 dimensional matrices, thus you need to find the right transformation that would project AB, Or, are they 3D matrices, then, you only need to perform rotations using Euler angles?

Comment: They are all 3D matrix. They all have a flat surface, which should be easier than a complexe shape to replace.

It would be easy if I could select some coordinate and define plan...

I will make an exemple for you to understand,

thank you

Comment: [Image Link](http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/96138537ex.jpg) (but the image is more complex, although it has at least 1 flat plan in each shape)

I am thinking to use surfaces (red and black) to rebuild AB with A and B...

Edit: Euler angles to perform a rotation, but how to reposition exactly the same as the original ? Is there a function ? I didt really get it :x

Answer (score 1):

I think of the following approach:

First obtain transform matrices that will take care of the relevant degrees of freedom. Then use a non-linear optimization to minimize the binary 3D difference.
About the degrees of freedom:
Each object at a (x,y,z) position and (theta,phi,psi) angluar orientation (Euler). So one would think you'll need 6+6=12 degrees of freedom (or dimensions) to perform a search. However, the dimensionality is lower, because you have the constraint that the 2 bodies must be present, so it is enough to look for the **relative** spatial separation (dx,dy,dz) and the relative angular difference (theta,phi,psi) . In addition, we can ask whether there is symmetry in the shapes, for example, if on of the shapes is a sphere, angles are irrelevant, etc..
So for each degree of freedom I'd expect to have a relevant 3x3 transformation matrices, Rtheta,Rphi,Rpsi,Tx,Ty,Tz. where Rtheta looks something like:

```
 Rtheta = [cos(theta)    0      -sin(theta)   0
           0             1              0     0
           sin(theta)    0       cos(theta)   0
           0             0              0     1];
```

These matrices can be combined a general rotation matrix

```
 Rot=Rtheta*Rphi*Rpsi;
```

and the similarly obtain the translation matrix Trans=Tx*Ty*Tz, Then

```
tform_Trans = maketform('affine', Trans);
tform_Rot = maketform('affine', Rot);
tform_RT = maketform('composite',tform_Rot,tform_Trans);
```

and the transform is applied using the function

```
 tformarray(A, tform_RT, R, TDIMS_A, TDIMS_B, TSIZE_B, TMAP_B, F)
```

Check out a more detailed account of this  in the following [link](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/08/17/spatial-transformations-three-dimensional-rotation/).

Comment: I checked your link and managed to get it working but something is definitely wrong : after rotating, my volume looks different. it becomes flat except if I make a rotation of 0 or pi/2...